# `gem install berkshelf` in windows fails

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra, berkshelf

I'm using this package to use `chef` in windows.
http://www.opscode.com/chef/install.msi

When I run `$ gem install berkshelf`, I got this error.
How can I fix this error?

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: dep_selector-1.0.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing berkshelf:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/opscode/chef/embedded/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lgecodesupport... yes
checking for main() in -lgecodesupport... yes
checking for main() in -lgecodekernel... yes
checking for main() in -lgecodeint... yes
checking for main() in -lgecodeminimodel... yes
checking for main() in -lgecodesearch... yes
creating Makefile

make
generating dep_gecode-i386-mingw32.def
compiling define_dummy_init.cxx
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/O
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C
compiling dep_selector_to_gecode.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/O
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C
In file included from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dep-selector-libge
0,
                 from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dep-selector-libge
45,
                 from C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dep-selector-libge

                 from dep_selector_to_gecode.cpp:20:
C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dep-selector-libgecode-1.0.0/lib/dep-sel
pscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dep-selector-libgecode-1.0.0/lib/dep-selecto
d
compilation terminated.
make: *** [dep_selector_to_gecode.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dep_s
Results logged to C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dep_selector-1.0.3/ext
```

This my environment.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
$ where ruby
C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin\ruby.exe
```

Comment: It looks like not available yet. http://www.getchef.com/downloads/chef-dk/windows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the same issue on Windows when using Git bash, but the berkshelf gem installed OK when using a command window.

Comment: This does provide an answer.  The responder has said that using the Git bash window will cause the gem install to fail, but using a regular command window will solve the problem.